# Matrix Multiplication CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, matrix-multiplication

I have been reading through several websites and even used [NVIDA's](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_sample_linear_algebra.html) code as a guide but I am still getting the wrong answer. The main will ask the user for size, and will display A and B then display the resulting matrix C. However say I run a 2x2 matrix for both A and B this is my sample output:

```
Matrix A
0.000000 8.000000
2.000000 2.000000


Matrix B
3.000000 1.000000
5.000000 7.000000


Matrix C (Results)
0.000000 9.000000
7.000000 4.000000
```

But that's incorrect. It should be:

```
40.000 56.000
16.000 16.000
```

I changed it from decimals to whole numbers so that it would be easier to check, and I found that it's incorrect. I do not understand why it would be incorrect, especially even though I took it right from their code sample.

```
#ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
#define _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

// Thread block size
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16
#define TILE_SIZE  16



// CUDA Kernel
__global__ void matrixMul( float* C, float* A, float* B, int wA, int wB)
{
    // Block index
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;

// Thread index
int tx = threadIdx.x;
int ty = threadIdx.y;

// Index of the first sub-matrix of A processed 
// by the block
int aBegin = wA * BLOCK_SIZE * by;

// Index of the last sub-matrix of A processed 
// by the block
int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;

// Step size used to iterate through the 
// sub-matrices of A
int aStep  = BLOCK_SIZE;

// Index of the first sub-matrix of B processed 
// by the block
int bBegin = BLOCK_SIZE * bx;

// Step size used to iterate through the 
// sub-matrices of B
int bStep  = BLOCK_SIZE * wB;
float Csub=0;
// Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B
// required to compute the block sub-matrix
for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep) 
{
    // Declaration of the shared memory array As 
    // used to store the sub-matrix of A
    __shared__ float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Declaration of the shared memory array Bs 
    // used to store the sub-matrix of B
    __shared__ float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Load the matrices from global memory
    // to shared memory; each thread loads
    // one element of each matrix
    As[ty][tx] = A[a + wA * ty + tx];
    Bs[ty][tx] = B[b + wB * ty + tx];

    // Synchronize to make sure the matrices 
    // are loaded
    __syncthreads();

    // Multiply the two matrices together;
    // each thread computes one element
    // of the block sub-matrix
    for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
        Csub += As[ty][k] * Bs[k][tx];

    // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
    // computation is done before loading two new
    // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
    __syncthreads();
}
// Write the block sub-matrix to device memory;
// each thread writes one element
int c = wB * BLOCK_SIZE * by + BLOCK_SIZE * bx;
C[c + wB * ty + tx] = Csub;
}

#endif // #ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
```

host code:

```
    //perform the calculation
    //setup execution parameters
    dim3 threads(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 grid(c.colSize / threads.x, c.rowSize / threads.y);

    //   execute the kernel
    matrixMul<<< grid, threads >>>(deviceMatrixC, deviceMatrixA, deviceMatrixB, a.colSize, b.colSize);
```

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Comment: The code you are using implicitly requires that the size of the matrices are round multiples of the block size (16x16 in this case). 2x2 matrices will not work. Try running with 16x16 inputs and confirming the result.

Comment: Thank you that did solve my issue. Is it only allowing a 16x16 because of it's block and tile size?

Comment: Yes. The inner product calculation processes a tile width at a time without checking for out of bounds memory access. That is where the error occurs.

Comment: @talonmies can you post your comment as an answer (to remove this from the unanswered list?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using implicitly requires that the size of the matrices are round multiples of the block size (16x16 in this case). The inner product calculation processes a tile width at a time without checking for out of bounds memory access. For this reason, 2x2 matrices will not work.

If you try running kernel with a 16x16 input (for example zero padding your 2x2 case to 16x16), you should be able to confirm the result.