# CUDA Matrix Multiplication write to wrong memory location

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, matrix-multiplication

The idea of my simple program that I've been trying to write is to take input from the user to see how large of a matrix to multiply.

```
dd@cuda-Linux:~/Desktop/multi$ ./program
What is the rowSize of a? 33
What is the colSize of a? 33
What is the rowSize of b? 33
What is the colSize of b? 33
Would you like to write the results to a file?(y or n)
y
Creating the random numbers now
Writing Matrix A to file now...
Writing Matrix B to file now...
Starting it on the device
Writing Matrix C to file now...
Finish
```

However the problems lies in my thread calculations. I can go to a 32x32 matrix and it will run fine and give me the correct results. However once I run a 33x33 I get results like the following:
[[Matrix A]](http://pastebin.com/iTgH6RyB) x [[Matrix B]](http://pastebin.com/jLU9pZRf) = [[Matrix C]](http://pastebin.com/tF5YWPPN) (linked to them instead of pasting several huge matrices into this post.   But with matrix c you can see that half way through it starts to write the wrong numbers. My graphics card has a limit of 1024 threads which is a 32x32 matrix. Also when I go to run a 100x100 matrix Matrix C is all 0s.

Let mem_size_X be sizeof(float) * size_X, and size_X is height*width of the matrix. Right now the height and width has to be the same thus 32x32. Also the "block_size" is just the height. So with a 32x32 matrix the block size corresponds to 32.
Host code(launching):

```
    float* deviceMatrixA;
    float* deviceMatrixB;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMatrixA, mem_size_A);//allocate mem_size_x on the device. 
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMatrixB, mem_size_B);


    cudaMemcpy(deviceMatrixA, a.elements, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceMatrixB, b.elements, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



    int size_C = c.rowSize * c.colSize;
    int mem_size_C = sizeof(float) * size_C;
    c.elements = (float*) malloc(mem_size_C);


    float* deviceMatrixC;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMatrixC, mem_size_C);


    dim3 threads(block_size, block_size);
    dim3 grid(c.colSize / threads.x, c.rowSize / threads.y);



    matrixMul<<< grid, threads,2*block_size*block_size*sizeof(float)>>>(deviceMatrixC, deviceMatrixA, deviceMatrixB, a.colSize, b.colSize, block_size);//sizeof(float)*block_size*block_size
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

The kernel code:

```
// CUDA Kernel
__global__ void matrixMul( float* C, float* A, float* B, int wA, int wB,size_t block_size)
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int aBegin = wA * block_size * by;
    int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;
    int aStep  = block_size;

    int bBegin = block_size * bx;

    int bStep  = block_size * wB;
    float Csub=0;

    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep) 
    {
        extern __shared__ float As[];
        extern __shared__ float Bs[];
        extern __shared__ float smem[];

        smem[ty*block_size+tx] = A[a + wA * ty + tx];

        smem[block_size*block_size+ty*block_size+tx]  = B[b + wB * ty + tx];

        __syncthreads();

        for (int k = 0; k < block_size; ++k)
            Csub += smem[ty*block_size+k] * smem[block_size*block_size+k*block_size+tx] ;

        __syncthreads();
    }

    int c = wB * block_size * by + block_size * bx;
    C[c + wB * ty + tx] = Csub;


}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matrix Multiplication CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813750/matrix-multiplication-cuda)

Comment: As I told you on your [earlier, almost identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813750/matrix-multiplication-cuda), this code is only designed to do calculations on matrices whose dimensions are a round multiple of `block_size`. If you choose `block_size=32`, then it can only be used for 32x32, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, etc. Nothing you have done with dynamically allocated shared memory changes this.

Comment: Then why does 1x1 through 32x32 work? All entered via the keyboard, but 33 does not. So I even tried the 64 x 64 and 128 by 128 like you said, and it yields a entire 0 matrix c.  Using the original code from my original question in the thread you linked, it would work with the 128x128.

Comment: I assure you, they don't work. But your code lacks the necessary error check to know that they don't work. I will post an answer showing that they don't work using my own repro case built around your kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you on your [earlier, almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8813750/681865), this matrix multiply code is only designed to do calculations on matrices whose dimensions are a round multiple of block_size. If you choose block_size=32, then it can only be used for 32x32, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, etc. Nothing you [have done with dynamically allocated shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9187899/681865) changes this.

To verify that this is the case, let's start with a complete, compilable repro case which will run your kernel, check whether it executed and compare its output to a simple reference calculation done on the host. This code is your posted kernel, plus the core of your launch parameter calculations. It will read a size from stdin and then run the case. If the results differ by more than a certain tolerance, an assert error will be raised. Here is the code, it should compile on CUDA 3.0 or later and run on any CUDA compatible GPU:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

inline void GPUassert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define GPUerrchk(ans) { GPUassert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

__global__ void matrixMul( float* C, float* A, float* B, int wA, int wB, size_t block_size)
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int aBegin = wA * block_size * by;
    int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;
    int aStep  = block_size;
    int bBegin = block_size * bx;
    int bStep  = block_size * wB;

    float Csub=0.f;
    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep) 
    {
        extern __shared__ float smem[];

        smem[ty*block_size+tx] = A[a + wA * ty + tx];
        smem[block_size*block_size+ty*block_size+tx]  = B[b + wB * ty + tx];

        __syncthreads();

        for (int k = 0; k < block_size; ++k)
            Csub += smem[ty*block_size+k] * smem[block_size*block_size+k*block_size+tx] ;

        __syncthreads();
    }

    int c = wB * block_size * by + block_size * bx;
    C[c + wB * ty + tx] = Csub;
}

inline float frand(){
    return (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}

void matmul(float *C, const float *A, const float *B,  int wA, int wB)
{
    for(int k=0; k<wB; k++) {
        for(int j=0; j<wB; j++) {
            float dotp = 0.f;
            for(int i=0; i<wA; i++) {
                dotp += A[j*wA+i] * B[i*wB+k];
            }
            C[j*wB+k] = dotp;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int val = 128;

    if ( argc == 2 ) {
        val = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    int m = val, n = val, mn = m*n;
    size_t sz = size_t(mn) * sizeof(float);

    srand(time(NULL));

    float * A = new float[mn], * B = new float[mn], * C= new float[mn];
    float * A_, * B_, * C_;

    for(int i=0; i<mn; i++) {
        A[i] = frand(); B[i] = frand();
    }

    GPUerrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&A_, sz) );
    GPUerrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&B_, sz) );
    GPUerrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&C_, sz) );

    GPUerrchk( cudaMemcpy(A_, A, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    GPUerrchk( cudaMemcpy(B_, B, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // Launch configuration
    // Note that the input matrice sizes *must* be a round
    // multiple of blocksize for this code to work correctly.
    const int blocksize=16;
    const int shmsz = size_t(2*blocksize*blocksize) * sizeof(float);
    dim3 block=dim3(blocksize,blocksize), grid = dim3(m/block.x,m/block.y); 

    matrixMul<<<grid,block,shmsz>>>(C_,A_,B_,m,n,blocksize);
    GPUerrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );

    GPUerrchk( cudaMemcpy(C, C_, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    // Verfication on host
    float * Cref = new float[mn];
    matmul(Cref,A,B,m,n); 
    const float tol = 5e-5f;
    for(int i=0; i<mn; i++) {
        assert(fabs(C[i]-Cref[i])/C[i] < tol);
    }

    GPUerrchk( cudaThreadExit() ); // CUDA 3.2 compatible

    return 0;
}
```

So now, let's run this code for different sizes. To verify that the code on the GPU didn't do anything wrong, I will run it using the cuda-memcheck utility, which can detect out of bounds memory access. All of the following tests were made on an OS X 10.6 machine with a compute capability 1.2 card and CUDA 3.2, using `blocksize=16` :

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_12 -Xcompiler="-Wall" -Xptxas="-v" -o matmul2 matmul2.cu
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9matrixMulPfS_S_iim' for 'sm_12'
ptxas info    : Used 16 registers, 32+16 bytes smem, 4 bytes cmem[1]
```

Let's try a case where the matrices are less than `blocksize` first

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 4
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
GPUassert: invalid configuration argument matmul2.cu 101
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Here we failed to run the kernel with an invalid configuration argument error. Why? Because of this:

```
    dim3 block=dim3(blocksize,blocksize), grid = dim3(m/block.x,m/block.y);
```

which results in a 0 grid size when `m,n < blocksize`.

Next let's try the smallest round multiple of blocksize, in this case 16:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 16
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

which runs without error, or assert failure. Let's now increase the size to 17:

```
cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 17
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
GPUassert: unspecified launch failure matmul2.cu 103
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000001f8 in matrixMul
=========     by thread (0,2,0) in block (0,0)
=========     Address 0x001009c8 is out of bounds
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

and we get out of bounds memory access detected and a launch failure error, which is expected. Now lets try 64, 96, and 128:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 64
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 96
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 128
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

and finally let's try 129:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./matmul2 129
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
GPUassert: unspecified launch failure matmul2.cu 103
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000001f8 in matrixMul
=========     by thread (0,1,0) in block (0,0)
=========     Address 0x00120904 is out of bounds
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

Even if you don't follow why the out of bounds errors are occurring, are you at least willing to accept that this code really does only work correctly for matrices which are round multiples of blocksize?

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for explaining it in detail. How do you suggest I go about to dynamically change the size of matrix it can accept.

Comment: There are a few ways you could do it. One way would be to zero pad the input/output matrices to the next largest multiple of the tile size and just extract the non zero portion afterwards. Another would be to add a second loop to the kernel code to finish the dot product over the portion of the matrices which don't cleanly fit into the tile. But this is really a separate question, and not something to be dealt with in comments here.

Comment: Ok I will start another topic.

Comment: I have started it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250897/dynamic-matrix-multiplication-with-cuda)